# rapid touches crash my game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've got a CCLayer class with touch enabled and the following methods:

```
    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

If I rapidly tap on the iPad screen repeatedly, it will crash-- but not to the point of getting a stack trace..  It will just freeze...  The console will read:

```
2012-10-17 08:43:06.445 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation stopped
2012-10-17 08:43:06.448 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 4.00
2012-10-17 08:43:07.075 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation stopped
2012-10-17 08:43:07.081 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2012-10-17 08:43:12.557 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation stopped
2012-10-17 08:43:12.561 game[5432:607] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 4.00
```

Is there a way to rate limit the ccTouchesBegan/ccTouchesEnded methods?  This even happens if I remove all the code inside those event handlers-- it's just the act of triggering that method ultra frequently that seems to bog everything down.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening in a new cocos2d project with just the touch modifications, too? If so, file a bug report on the cocos2d forum.

The log seems to indicate that cocos2d is either being paused or stopped, or both. Check if the CCDirector functions `startAnimation`, `stopAnimation`, `pause` and `resume` are being called by setting a breakpoint. Check the callstack who is making these calls. If it comes from your code, fix it. If not and this happens in a new project, file a bug report.